# Disable jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have three buttons: first open,  second disable,  and third enable. When user click on disable button then jquery ui dialog should be disabled and not open on click on open button. After that, if user click on enable then dialog should be enabled and open on open dialog click.

[example:-](http://jsfiddle.net/2dha9/)

code:-

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });

    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  });
```

Any help should be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

```
var isEnable=1;
     $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
          if(isEnable)
             $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
      });
     $( "#enabler" ).click(function() {
             isEnable=1; 
      });
     $( "#disablerr" ).click(function() {
             isEnable=0;
      });
```

Other way is disable/enable button using jquery but I think this is better option if you do not have css disable effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to keep track of whether the dialog is enabled.

```
var dialog_enabled = true;

$("#opener").click(function () {
    if (dialog_enabled) {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    }
});

$("#disable_dialog").click(function() {
    dialog_enabled = false;
});
$("#enable_dialog").click(function() {
    dialog_enabled = true;
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2dha9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Prince You can set a global variable with on the button clicks and can handle the enabling and disabling of the dialog based on that global variable like below:

```
  var isDisabled=false;
         $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
              if(!isDisabled)
                 $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
          });
         $( "#enabler" ).click(function() {
                 isDisabled=true; 
          });
         $( "#disablerr" ).click(function() {
                 isDisabled=false;
          });
```